# Is it safe to update LaTeX package with tlmgr on debian?

Tags: packages, texlive, updating, debian

I using debian (unstable) and have installed most of my LaTeX packages from the official repositories (except few ones which I copied directly inside a folder recognized by `texhash`).

I just learned it is possible to update package with `tlmgr` utility and commands like :

```
tlmgr update --self --all
```

I am wondering how this command is "safe" on my debian. Indeed, if I update my texlive distro like this, my packages will be newer than what debian offers (inside meta-packages like `texlive-latex-extra`). So, what happens when there is a debian update? Isn't there some kind of conflict?

Comment: Short answer: no. Why? Because you do this in bypassing the package manager. And that's evil. And if `texlive-latex-extra` will be updated - it will rewrite all files updated by `tlmgr`.

Comment: @someonr I did : I specified "unstable" (sid). Unstable is always changing and, so, I can't be more specific.

Comment: @ppr Sry, Looks like I was sleeping yesterday.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The *unstable* debian versions `sid` and `Jessie` provide `tlmgr` (as you may lookup [here](http://packages.debian.org/search?suite=sid&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=tlmgr)). You may use it, because it runs in user mode (see [the doc](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html#USER-MODE) or the [man page](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=tlmgr&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%20unstable%20sid&format=html&locale=en)). That means it will write the new/updated packages to your home folder and won't conflict with the package manager. PDFLaTex etc. prefer the packages from your home folder.

The tlmgr executable isn't included in any *stable* debian (see [here](http://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=tlmgr&mode=exactfilename&suite=wheezy&arch=any)). So you can't update with `tlmgr`. You can install texlive manually to `/usr/local/texlive` without messing up the debian package manger (this is the default directory). `/usr/local` won't be touched by the official debian packages (see the [debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/FilesystemHierarchyStandard)). After doing this you may use `tlmgr` to update your texlive packages. (I'm doing this on ubuntu without any problems)

Comment: In Debian, `tlmgr` is installed when you installed texlive. There is no package with this name but the commandline works. however, this was not my question : I don't want to know how to update with `tlmgr` but only if it is safe or not.

Comment: @ppr Sry I wasn't aware that it is included in the unstable debian versions. I'm updating my answer.

Comment: It's getting clear but it still seems to me odd that **two** different versions of the same package are installed on the same system. And what can I do if I decide to change my mind and want to go back to the "official" debian repositories? simply delete the folder created by `tlmgr` inside my home folder?

Comment: @ppr: Yes. Or deinstall these packages with tlmgr (which should only work on your folder).

Comment: @ppr That's part of the 'design': your local tree is just for you, and can override the 'managed' tree. That idea is independent of using `tlmgr`.

Comment: I'll throw in some information for people who stumble on this page now, years after this answer was given. When this answer was originally posted/edited, it was correct. However, since then, Jessie has gone stable, and tlmgr is still available. The remarks about safety still apply, though [it will only run in "user mode," so it has no effect on apt(itude or -get), so it's not a problem to use it].